# How to find location in database of CPU intensive query?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, dbo

I have a server called "Reporting" and looking at SQL Server performance reports, specifically "Top Queries by Total CPU Time". I have found the top CPU Time consuming queries.

The number 1 query shows me the "Query Text", "Database Name", "Object ID" and "Total CPU Time".

I would like to go and optimize the code of that query but I only know the database where the query is from but not the exact location folder or name of the query.

Is there any way of how one can go about finding the exact name and location of the query?

```
 For Example:
Top CPU Expensive Query is in Database "Training", ObjectID "1727285326", Query text +- 500 lines of SQL code. 
Where do I go look in the "Training" Database for the query since I only see the Query Text and Object ID?
```

Any help or right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the object id you can just use the following to find the object

```
USE Training;

SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(1727285326) AS schema_name,
       OBJECT_NAME(1727285326)        AS object_name;
```

Comment: Martin, what method do you use if you only have the Query Text, but no Database name and Object ID? Because in the top 10 list some of them do not have those values when running that performance report.